# Flutter - How to tint an image's black color only, without touching transparent or white part?

Tags: image, flutter, tint

For an image like below, it has some white parts which I want to keep it white, transparent background which I want untouched, and black parts which I want to tint dynamically to e.g. green, red, etc.

In iOS I could get the effect using blending methods like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
draw(in: rect)
color.set()
UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(rect, .screen)
draw(in: rect, blendMode: .destinationIn, alpha: color.alpha())
```

But I haven't been able to find a way to color it in Flutter - help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install [Image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) Package

Import package

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;
```

Then use the following code to change the background color of the image

```
Future<Uint8List> changeBackgroundOfImage(
      {@required Uint8List bytes,
      @required List<int> removeColorRGB,
      @required List<int> addColorRGB}) async {
    Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(bytes);
    Img.Image newImage = await _customeColor(
        src: image, removeColorRGB: removeColorRGB, addColorRGB: addColorRGB);
    var newPng = Img.encodePng(newImage);
    return newPng;
  }

Future<Img.Image> _customeColor(
      {Img.Image src, List<int> removeColorRGB, List<int> addColorRGB}) async {
    var pixels = src.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0, len = pixels.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      if (pixels[i] == removeColorRGB[0] &&
          pixels[i + 1] == removeColorRGB[1] &&
          pixels[i + 2] == removeColorRGB[2]) {
        pixels[i] = addColorRGB[0];
        pixels[i + 1] = addColorRGB[1];
        pixels[i + 2] = addColorRGB[2];
      }
    }

    return src;
  }
```

Note: Above function requires three-argument first is bytes of image, second and third is removeColorRGB, addColorRGB which is a List of an RGB value, see below line of code

```
Uint8List newbyte = await changeBackgroundOfImage(
bytes: bytes, removeColorRGB: [0, 0, 0], addColorRGB: [66, 245, 120]);
```

Full Code:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;

class BlendMode extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<Uint8List> changeBackgroundOfImage(
      {@required Uint8List bytes,
      @required List<int> removeColorRGB,
      @required List<int> addColorRGB}) async {
    Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(bytes);
    Img.Image newImage = await _customeColor(
        src: image, removeColorRGB: removeColorRGB, addColorRGB: addColorRGB);
    var newPng = Img.encodePng(newImage);
    return newPng;
  }

  static Future<Img.Image> _customeColor(
      {Img.Image src, List<int> removeColorRGB, List<int> addColorRGB}) async {
    var pixels = src.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0, len = pixels.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      if (pixels[i] == removeColorRGB[0] &&
          pixels[i + 1] == removeColorRGB[1] &&
          pixels[i + 2] == removeColorRGB[2]) {
        pixels[i] = addColorRGB[0];
        pixels[i + 1] = addColorRGB[1];
        pixels[i + 2] = addColorRGB[2];
      }
    }

    return src;
  }
  
  convertImage() async {
    ByteData imageData1 = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/Vgv5e.png");
    Uint8List bytes = imageData1.buffer.asUint8List();

    Uint8List newbyte = await AppUtils.changeBackgroundOfImage(
    bytes: bytes, removeColorRGB: [0, 0, 0], addColorRGB: [66, 245, 120]);

    return newbyte;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: convertImage(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) => Image.memory(snapshot.data)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Important**: It is important that your image background must be in one color means the background should not be in shade or gradient to remove background color completely

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Almost there, 2 issues: 1. If you enlarge the image and look at its white border closely, you can see a few grayish pixels around it as a usual rendering blurring effect - on iOS that part is replaced with the new color too but here only the exact black color is replaced (I tried to do a pixel diff absolute value < 50 for example, but still the effect is not good). 2. Could there be a non-async way of doing it utilizing Image.blendMode plus ColorFiltered?